# Ng-repeat not updating view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have read multiple question threads from people with a simmilar issue but they didn't solve my problem.

This is  the full code(Exluding the CSS portion:

```
 <script>                                       

   var app = angular.module("game", []);
   app.controller("controlematrix",function($scope)
        {   
            $scope.undo = [];
            $scope.matriz = [ 2,2,2,2,2,2,2
                             ,2,2,2,0,0,0,2
                             ,2,3,0,0,0,0,2
                             ,2,0,0,0,0,0,2                    
                             ,2,3,0,0,2,0,2
                             ,2,0,0,0,0,0,2  
                             ,2,2,2,2,2,2,2];

            $scope.posx = 5;
            $scope.posy = 3;

            $scope.testeshow= function(atual){                  
                return (($scope.posx + $scope.posy * 7) != atual);  
            }

            $scope.up = function() {
                if($scope.matriz[$scope.posx + ($scope.posy-1) * 7] != 2)
                {
                    $scope.posy--;
                }
            }
            $scope.down = function() {
                if($scope.matriz[$scope.posx + ($scope.posy+1) * 7] != 2)
                {
                    $scope.posy++;
                }
            }
            $scope.left = function() {
                if($scope.matriz[($scope.posx-1) + $scope.posy * 7] != 2)
                {
                    $scope.posx--;
                }
            }
            $scope.right = function() {
                if($scope.matriz[($scope.posx+1) + $scope.posy * 7] != 2)
                {
                    $scope.posx++;
                }
            }

        });
</script>
```

```
<div id="everything" ng-app="game" ng-controller="controlematrix" >
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat= "x in matriz track by $index">
            <img ng-src="{{'tile' + x +'.png'}}"  alt="tile" ng-show= "{{testeshow($index)}}"> 
            <img ng-src="player.png"  alt="player" ng-show= "{{!testeshow($index)}}"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonscreen">
        <button class="botao" ng-click="up()">UP</button>
        <button class="botao" ng-click="down()">DOWN</button>
        <button class="botao" ng-click="left()">LEFT</button>
        <button class="botao" ng-click="right()">RIGHT</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

After debugging, it seems the posx and posy values are updating like they should but the image onscreen stays the same.I can't seem to find where the problem is. If someone can help I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng-show="{{testeshow($index)}}"` to `ng-show="testeshow($index)"`. [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) expects an expression.

Comment: Please write answer in case if  your answer is different from others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove `{{}}` from `ng-show`

```
<img ng-src="{{'tile' + x +'.png'}}"  alt="tile" 
     ng-show= "testeshow($index)"> 
<img ng-src="player.png"  alt="player" 
     ng-show= "!testeshow($index)">
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQTyGoCvwOITr5HKlmIW?p=preview)